# MySQL order by duplicates top first

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have a lammer question, as far as I am not pro at mysql

I have fields like

```
   id    color
   1     red
   2     green
   3     yellow
   4     green
   5     green
   6     red
```

I want to group by duplicates , and most frequent duplicate first
so it should be selected this way:

```
   id    color
   2     green
   4     green
   5     green
   1     red
   6     red
   3     yellow
```

thanks

Answer (score 9):

> *"...most frequent duplicate first."*

query,

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    TableName a
        INNER JOIN 
        (
            SELECT  Color, COUNT(*) totalCount
            FROM    TableName
            GROUP   BY Color
        ) b ON  a.Color = b.Color
ORDER   BY b.TotalCount DESC, a.ID ASC
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f9938/2)

OUTPUT

```
╔════╦════════╗
║ ID ║ COLOR  ║
╠════╬════════╣
║  2 ║ green  ║
║  4 ║ green  ║
║  5 ║ green  ║
║  1 ║ red    ║
║  6 ║ red    ║
║  3 ║ yellow ║
╚════╩════════╝
```

Comment: Thanks! This for perfect for my requirements. The only adjustment I had to do was using the same WHERE clause both in the outer and inner queries, but the general idea of your answer was very useful as a baseline to work upon.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT ID, COLOR
FROM MYTABLE A
JOIN
(
SELECT COLOR, COUNT(*) CN
FROM MYTABLE
GROUP BY COLOR
) B
ON B.COLOR = A.COLOR
ORDER BY B.CN, A.ID
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the query:

```
SELECT B.* FROM
(
    SELECT color,COUNT(1) occurrences
    FROM colortable GROUP BY color
) A LEFT JOIN colortable B USING (color)
ORDER BY A.occurrences DESC,color;
```

Here is the sample data

```
mysql> use test
Database changed
mysql> DROP TABLE colortable;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE colortable
    -> (
    ->     id int not null auto_increment,
    ->     color varchar(20),
    ->     primary key (id)
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.05 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO colortable (color) VALUES
    -> ('red'),('green'),('yellow'),
    -> ('green'),('green'),('red');
Query OK, 6 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 6  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT * from colortable;
+----+--------+
| id | color  |
+----+--------+
|  1 | red    |
|  2 | green  |
|  3 | yellow |
|  4 | green  |
|  5 | green  |
|  6 | red    |
+----+--------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Here is the query's execution:

```
mysql>     SELECT B.* FROM
    ->     (
    ->         SELECT color,COUNT(1) occurrences
    ->         FROM colortable GROUP BY color
    ->     ) A LEFT JOIN colortable B USING (color)
    ->     ORDER BY A.occurrences DESC,color;
+------+--------+
| id   | color  |
+------+--------+
|    2 | green  |
|    4 | green  |
|    5 | green  |
|    6 | red    |
|    1 | red    |
|    3 | yellow |
+------+--------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Give it a Try !!!