# Order by duplicates top first with limit

Tags: mysql, sql

I have already asked similar question here [MySQL order by duplicates top first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15812870/mysql-order-by-duplicates-top-first)

How about limiting duplicates, say not more than 2 distinct

I have fields like

```
   id    color
   1     red
   2     green
   3     yellow
   4     green
   5     green
   6     red
   7     red
```

I want to group by duplicates , and most frequent duplicate first
so it should be selected this way:

```
   id    color
   2     green
   4     green
   1     red
   6     red
   3     yellow
```

thank you guys

Comment: So you want the latest two with the min id's for those that has more than two entries for each `color`? But this is not just ordering, you want to limit the selected for each color.

Answer (score 1):

There is a logical problem. "Distinct" is not working, because the query result row is unique in combination of the "id" and the "color" value. It will only works if you remove the id column from the column list in the select. Otherwise use can use an aggregat function like "max/min/avg/count" - i would prefer the max/min function - to get at least one of the ids?

If you want to count the colors, try this:

```
Select count(color) as number_of_colors, color FROM table GROUP BY color ORDER BY count(color) DESC
```

Comment: that is not an answer dude.

Answer (score 1):

This query shows at maximum two id for every colour, ordered by the number of duplicates in descending order:

```
SELECT
  c1.id,
  c1.color
FROM
  colors c1 INNER JOIN (SELECT color, COUNT(*) c FROM colors GROUP BY color) dup
  ON c1.color = dup.color
  LEFT JOIN colors c2
  ON c1.id > c2.id AND c1.color=c2.color
GROUP BY
  c1.color, c1.id
HAVING
  COUNT(c2.id) < 2
ORDER BY
  MAX(dup.c) DESC, c1.color, c1.id
```

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5329c/8).